# GNUcash - temporary funds received for purchase?

Tags: gnucash, rent, cash

Where I live we have an app where we can transfer cash to each other. This morning for example, my girlfriend sent me 3750 so that I'd send 7500 to our landlord for rent. Where would i get these funds received from her in gnucash? I put the expense under the correct expense account but wouldn't this cash i received from her skew my "income" if i put it there? I guess the whole rent falling on me also would skew my expenses. How would you people do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that the whole rent should not fall on yourself, unless your "business entity" represents joint ownership of assets.

On the day where the rent is due according to lease agreement:

> DR Expense:Rent **3750**
>
> DR Current Asset:Receivables/Debtors:Girlfriend **3750**
>
> CR Current Asset:Bank **7500**

On the day where the share of rent was received from girlfriend:

> DR Current Asset:Bank **3750**
>
> CR Current Asset:Receivables/Debtors:Girlfriend **3750**

Note that depending on whether the girlfriend pays in advance or in arrears, Debtor could become Creditor instead.

Comment: I'm new to the terminology here, what does DR and CR mean ?

Comment: Sorry. Debit and Credit in GNUCash. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debits_and_credits

Comment: I'm not sure i quite follow, would it be possible for you to summarize it in words ? Who is the "bank" account in this scenariou up here? I almost understand it

Comment: Everything is "You". Your Rent, Your Girlfriend, Your Bank Account.

Comment: So she sends me the money in advance. How can i add a balance into "current asset receivables/debtors" without it going to imbalance, where does this come from ?

Comment: And thank you for your patience with me <3

Comment: It comes from Increasing an Asset (Bank) and Increasing a Creditor (Girlfriend) at the same time. It's like someone gave you money, but you have to give it back (albeit back to Landlord).

Comment: And bank here would be my bank account? They're both listed as assets, can i increase 2 assets at the same time with this double transaction book-keping law the program follows? Isn't it an addition and subtraction thing .v

Comment: HANG ON my program is in my language, i didn't understand receivable was an account type

Comment: Need to click Split Transaction to create 3-way entry. Don't think too much about increase/decrease. Focus on Debit = Left Side and Credit = Right Side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107151/discussion-between-dakkvader-and-base64).